# How to find Resolvent Kernel?

Tags: integral-equations

Find the resolvent kernel associated with the kernel $K(x,t) = |x-t|$ in the interval $(0,1)$ ?

I tried solving it but I am stuck at the part where we have to split the integral.

Answer (score 0):

[image: The Solution for K2]

Similarly you can proceed to find K2 for the case x>E.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If you felt the answer was satisfactory, please feel free to accept it and upvote! :)